# Ubuntu pervasive RubyGems

Tags: bash, rubygems, linux-terminal

Hey guys I downloaded the Pagodabox gem via

`gem install pagoda` which gives me the terminal command `$ pagoda`

From here I can run all of my fun pagoda commands like

```
$ pagoda -a app tunnel -c whatever
$ pagoda destroy
```

and etcetra, good to go...

BUT if I close my terminal, I no longer have access to the command pagoda,
it is evidently non-pervasive =( which means I need to reinstall the gem
which already exists locally and bleh....

I guess the real question is, how to make these command line gems pervasive?
I'd love to be able to fire up my terminal and go, but....

thanks!

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I wonder what Ubuntu has screwed up to make this happen.

Comment: Yeah not really sure to tell you the truth? I thought it was wonky too. I'mm on 12.04 LTS curr

Comment: It sounds like what can happen when you are running RVM.  Or another environment manager.  The gems, in that case, are installed in whatever environment you are in at the moment.

When you log in again, you simply aren't in the same environment.  Please do the same thing again, but before logging out of your terminal, type in `gem which pagoda` and that will give us more insight.